# how to configure wsl installaton in windows 10

Tags: windows, wsl-2

I wanted to install wsl in my windows 10 but I am getting this message
C:\WINDOWS\system32>wsl --install
The specified service does not exist as an installed service.
Error code: Wsl/CallMsi/0x80070424

I even tried to install it manually and the installation was successful but when I run wsl --status it's giving me this same error message The specified service does not exist as an installed service.
Error code: Wsl/CallMsi/0x80070424

```
Please I need help on how to resolve it because without it, I cannot be able to install my Docker
```

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I ran into this recently after installing updates.

Comment: Yes, I solved it by clicking on repair and it updated it @Hellma